# Converting dataframe to date format

Tags: r

i have a dataframe containing 250 columns of dates and in time in character format except for column 1 which contains Employee ID id.  How can i convert all the columns except 1st column to date format.

```
1   1/5/2015 17:20  1/6/2015 17:19  1/7/2015 16:34  1/8/2015 17:08
2   1/2/2015 18:22  1/5/2015 17:48  NA              1/7/2015 17:09
3   1/2/2015 16:59  1/5/2015 17:06  1/6/2015 16:38  1/7/2015 16:33
4   1/2/2015 17:25  1/5/2015 17:14  1/6/2015 17:07  1/7/2015 16:32
5   1/2/2015 18:31  1/5/2015 17:49  1/6/2015 17:26  1/7/2015 17:37
6   1/2/2015 20:29  1/5/2015 20:57  1/6/2015 21:06  1/7/2015 20:36
```

Above date and in time of employee are in character format.

Tried doing 
`parse_date_time(df[,-1],"ymd_HMS")` and `parse_date_time(df[,2:250],"ymd_HMS")`

but the same is not working.  However while specifying only one column the syntax is working.  Practically to do for 250 codes by individually specifying each columns is bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `strtime` function to turn your character values into datetime values.

```
df[,2:250] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,2:250], strptime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

The `df[,2:250]` will take only the columns you are interested in.

The format `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` describes the format of your character entries. You can see what the letters mean [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

Comment: Thanks.  This worked.  I only had to change the syntax slightly as df[,2:250] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[,2:250], strptime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

Comment: @VikramRS I have changed it accordingly